# What is a bold blaze in the Minecraft DW20 pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-direwolf20

I went to the nether, killed a bunch of blazes, and now I realize that I have two new morphs - "Blaze" and "Bold Blaze".

I can detect absolutely no difference between the two. They have the same amount of hearts, they both hate water, and they're exactly the same size.

What's the difference between a "Blaze" and a "Bold Blaze" in this pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was added by Thaumcraft. Sickly, bold, etc vanilla mobs sometimes drop little [bags of treasures](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_Bag) (common, uncommon and rarely rare).

If you get one, it's almost guaranteed that you'll get some gold coins. You might also get:

- Ender pearls
- Knowledge fragments
- Emeralds
- Other random but generally useful loot.

If you have an automated mob grinder set up, consider using an autonomous activator to automatically get the loot, and something like a hopper or vacuum chest from Ender IO to collect it.

Figured this out after dealing with what looked like a vanilla spider that just wouldn't die early game :)

Comment: The "other random but generally useful loot" are gold ingots, diamonds and any kind of vanilla potion.